# double number multiplication is not working in Grails, under ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: ubuntu, grails, double, multiplication

I am multiplying double numbers in `Grails 2.2.1` and saving it as the  `string`.It is working fine under local environment(windows 7 , jdk 7, tomcat7) but not working under the `ubuntu server` (14.04, tomcat7 , jdk7).I am not able to find out the root cause behind it.

Here is the `error log`

```
public java.lang.Number java.lang.Number#multiply(java.lang.Number).Stacktrace follows:

org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodSelectionException: Could not find which method multiply() to invoke from this list:

  public java.lang.Number java.lang.Number#multiply(java.lang.Character)
  public java.lang.Number java.lang.Number#multiply(java.lang.Number)

    at sagoon.ProductsController.addDiamondProduct(ProductsController.groovy:232)

    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)

    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

`code` **snippest**

```
 def today = new Date().clearTime()
    def todayGoldPrice = GoldRates.findAllByGoldDate(today)
    def category = Categories.get(params.category)
    def karigad = Karigads.get(params.karigad)

    Double totalDiamondAmount = params.diamondWeight.toDouble() * params.diamondRate.toDouble()

    Double totalGoldAmount = params.goldWeight.toDouble() * ( params.goldPercent.toDouble()/100 )  * todayGoldPrice.rate

    Double totalMc = params.goldWeight.toDouble() * params.mcPerGram.toDouble()

    Double totalStoneAmount = params.stoneWeight.toDouble() * params.stonePricePerCarat.toDouble()

    Double totalPurchasePrice = totalDiamondAmount.toDouble() + totalGoldAmount.toDouble() + totalStoneAmount.toDouble() + totalMc.toDouble()
```

**ProductsController.addDiamondProduct**

```
 def addDiamondProduct(){

    def today = new Date().clearTime()
    def todayGoldPrice = GoldRates.findAllByGoldDate(today)
    def category = Categories.get(params.category)
    def karigad = Karigads.get(params.karigad)

    Double totalDiamondAmount = params.diamondWeight.toDouble() * params.diamondRate.toDouble()
    Double totalGoldAmount = params.goldWeight.toDouble() * ( params.goldPercent.toDouble()/100 )  * todayGoldPrice.rate
    Double totalMc = params.goldWeight.toDouble() * params.mcPerGram.toDouble()
    Double totalStoneAmount = params.stoneWeight.toDouble() * params.stonePricePerCarat.toDouble()
    Double totalPurchasePrice = totalDiamondAmount.toDouble() + totalGoldAmount.toDouble() + totalStoneAmount.toDouble() + totalMc.toDouble()

    def product = new DiamondProducts(
            productCode: params.productCode,
            diamondWeight: params.diamondWeight,
            diamondRate: params.diamondRate,
            totalDiamondAmount: totalDiamondAmount.toString(),
            goldWeight: params.goldWeight,
            goldKt: params.goldPurity,
            goldPercent: params.goldPercent,
            totalGoldAmount: totalGoldAmount.toString(),
            mcGram: params.mcPerGram,
            totalMc: totalMc.toString(),
            stoneWeight: params.stoneWeight,
            stonePricePerCarat: params.stonePricePerCarat,
            totalStoneAmount: totalStoneAmount.toString(),
            totalPurchasePrice: totalPurchasePrice.toString(),
            salePrice: params.salePrice,
            remarks: params.remarks,
            description: params.description,
            itemNumber: params.itemNumber,
            karigad: karigad,
            category: category,
            status: "notSold",
            createdDate: new Date()
    )
    product.save()

    flash.message = "Product Added Successfully."
    redirect(action: 'diamondProducts')

}
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You should also add the code for `ProductsController.addDiamondProduct(..)`. As based on your stacktrace the origin of the failed call of `Number#multiply()` is there.

Comment: Can you add the code for `ProductsController.addDiamondProduct`

Comment: which line is this `(ProductsController.groovy:232)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so that it's giving you this error due to different working environment.I have tested it on the `Ubuntu 14.04` environment and it is working just fine.

You can see in your `error log` that, at the `run-time` groovy engine is getting confused with the `multiply` method.It is not able to select the any one of the method as there are two options available and that's why it's giving `MethodSelectionException`.

```
public java.lang.Number java.lang.Number#multiply(java.lang.Character)
public java.lang.Number java.lang.Number#multiply(java.lang.Number)
```

Also please have a look at below lines in the `code` snippet added by you

```
def todayGoldPrice = GoldRates.findAllByGoldDate(today)
.
.
.
Double totalGoldAmount = params.goldWeight.toDouble() * ( params.goldPercent.toDouble()/100 )  * todayGoldPrice.rate
```

Here in the the first line you have done `findAllByGoldDate` query on the `Domain class` `GoldRates`.
The `findAllByGoldDate` will return the list of objects matching the query criteria.

In the another line where you are doing the multiplication, look at the way you are accessing the `rate` field from the `todayGoldPrice` collection which has list of objects.I recommend you to replace `findAllBy` with `findBy` if you want to access the `rate` field directly like `todayGoldPrice.rate` which you have done in your code.

Please look into it and if possible use the same database dump in both the environment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can i fix this?  I could not think of any solution.

Comment: Can you please add the code for `ProductsController.addDiamondProduct`? I might able to give you the solution by looking into it.

Comment: I have updated the question with ProductsController.addDiamondProduct . Please have a look.

Comment: @AadityaBhatta Can you please also tell me what you have on the `line number` 232?

Comment: In windows environment `database` you might be having the single entry for the `todayGoldPrice` for specified `date(today)`  and that's why you will be getting single object but that might ot be the case on the Ubuntu environment database, which is causing this probelm.Use same database dump in both the environment and let me know the result.

Comment: I used the same database, still it works in my local computer without any exception. and i have Double totalStoneAmount = params.stoneWeight.toDouble() * params.stonePricePerCarat.toDouble() on line number 232. There might be some other problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123903/discussion-between-abhinandan-and-aaditya-bhatta).

Comment: Actually in ubuntu server, i was trying to call addDiamondProduct action without setting todayGoldPrice. You were right about the error regarding goldRate. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I am glad that it helped you.Happy coding:)